# save the current location in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, save, location

i am having an issue that i am updating my location after every 10 sec. i want to store my starting position as well on firebase .... i cant understand how to store the starting point because the firebase is updating ... here is my code

```
 i am having an issue that i am updating my location after every 10 sec. i want to store my starting position as well on firebase .... i cant understand how to store the starting point because the firebase is updating ... here is my code
```

i am having an issue that i am updating my location after every 10 sec. i want to store my starting position as well on firebase .... i cant understand how to store the starting point because the firebase is updating ... here is my code

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;



import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;


public class Location_activity extends Activity implements LocationListener  , ScheduledExecutorService{
    private TextView latituteField, longitudeField;
    private LocationManager lm;
    private String provider;
    private Button startbtn , cancelbtn;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseref;
    FirebaseUser current_user;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_activity);


        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
        startbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        cancelbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);

        startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

                scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        Location myLocation = null;
                        if (lm != null) {
                            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Location_activity.this,
                                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Location_activity.this,
                                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                                return;
                            }

                                myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);




                            if (myLocation == null) {
                                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
                                String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                                myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                            }

                            if (myLocation == null) {
                                myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            }
                            if (myLocation != null){
                                System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
                                onLocationChanged(myLocation);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }, 1, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                      scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdown();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
            double lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());



            current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            String uid = current_user.getUid();
            mDatabaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("location").child(uid);
            String device_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

            HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
            userMap.put("latitude", String.valueOf(lat));
            userMap.put("longitude" , String.valueOf(lng));

            userMap.put("device_token", device_token);
            mDatabaseref.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Location updated" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
            });


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(@NonNull Runnable command, long delay, @NonNull TimeUnit unit) {
        return null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <V> ScheduledFuture<V> schedule(@NonNull Callable<V> callable, long delay, @NonNull TimeUnit unit) {
        return null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(@NonNull Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, @NonNull TimeUnit unit) {
        return null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleWithFixedDelay(@NonNull Runnable command, long initialDelay, long delay, @NonNull TimeUnit unit) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isShutdown() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTerminated() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, @NonNull TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return false;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T> Future<T> submit(@NonNull Callable<T> task) {
        return null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T> Future<T> submit(@NonNull Runnable task, T result) {
        return null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Future<?> submit(@NonNull Runnable task) {
        return null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(@NonNull Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks) throws InterruptedException {
        return null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(@NonNull Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks, long timeout, @NonNull TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T> T invokeAny(@NonNull Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T invokeAny(@NonNull Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks, long timeout, @NonNull TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(@NonNull Runnable command) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = 0;

mDatabaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("location").child(uid);
String device_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
userMap.put("Startlatitude", String.valueOf(lat));
userMap.put("Startlongitude" , String.valueOf(lng));
userMap.put("Currentlatitude" , String.valueOf(lat));
userMap.put("Currentlongitude" , String.valueOf(lng));

if(i==0) {

    userMap.put("device_token", device_token);
    mDatabaseref.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Location updated" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            i++;
        }
    });
}
else {
    userMap.child("Currentlatitude").setValue(String.valueOf(lat));
    userMap.child("Currentlongitude").setValue(String.valueOf(lng));

    // Attach addOnCompleteListener
    // You  can also use HashMap to update both together.
}
```

So only first time latitude and longitude will be saved in database, as i=0 initially. When starting lat, long will be saved i is incremented. So from next time else condition will be always true.I hope this will do your job.

Comment: thanks .... but i think you have to pass  this......... userMap.put("Startlatitude", String.valueOf(lat));
userMap.put("Startlongitude" , String.valueOf(lng));    under if condition.... then it will stop if i > 0...

Comment: The startLat and startLong will save only once. But else will run every time when i==0, so you can get the update lat and long.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have added a listener on your location and everytime the location changes, you are getting a new `Location` object that contains the new coordinates and these new coordinates you are writing them into the database everytime. If you want to write only the starting point into the database you should declare a boolean named `isStartingPointWritten` with the default value of false.

```
boolean isStartingPointWritten = false;
```

And then just simply write a condition like this:

```
if(!isStartingPointWritten) {
    // write your userMap to the database
    isStartingPointWritten = true;
}
```

In this way you can restrict the write operation to take place only once.